# What is the difference between load_digits() and fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, mnist

I would like to know the difference between

```
from sklearn import datasets
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")
```

and

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
tempdigits = load_digits()
```

How is these two related to MNIST dataset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sklearn comes with a few small standard datasets that do not require to download any file from some external website.
load_digits includes around 1800 samples of size 8X8 from the UCI ML dataset:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Optical+Recognition+of+Handwritten+Digits

fetch_mldata downloads the MNist dataset from 
http://mldata.org/repository/data/viewslug/mnist-original/
which contains 70000 samples of size 28x28 pixels

So basically the datasets downloaded are different.

Comment: Are these two different from standard MNIST dataset?

Comment: The dataset fetched by fetch_mldata is the original MNIST dataset. The dataset fetched by load_digits is preprocessed version with some modification. The UCI link specifies what were the changes done.